# typeorm: параметры конфигурации

Tags: typescript, typeorm

кто может пояснить связь между параметрами конфига: entities и autoLoadEntities? они взаимоислючающие? что реально дает каждый из параметров?

Answer (score 0):

В [typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) нет параметра конфигурации [autoLoadEntities](https://www.google.com/search?q=autoLoadEntities%20site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ftypeorm.io).